# Find the range of $k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $p+q+k=2$ and $4pq+pk+kq=3$ ,where $p, q , k$ are real numbers ,find the range of values of $k$.

I feel like that it is related to quadratics (so that we can use the fact that the discriminant is non-negative)but I can't proceed

Comment: Solve the first equation for p, then substitute it in to the second equation. Collect powers of p in the resulting equation (it's quadratic in p, and the coefficients are polynomials in terms of k). Then you should be able to calculate the discriminant as you suggested, and the discriminant is quadratic in terms of k.

Comment: Right, I was trying to create a quadratic equation in $k$ and it didn't work. I felt like that was a right direction but I was not doing it properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As, $p+q+k=2$, we have $p+q=2-k$.

The second equation becomes $4pq=3-k(2-k)$ .

Note that $(p-q)^2=(p+q)^2-4pq=(2-k)^2-3+k(2-k)=1-2k$.

We see that $1-2k \ge 0$ which gives $k\le \frac{1}{2}$ .

Comment: [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) is a reference for mathjax.

Comment: That is really really inspiring.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh will follow that......

Comment: @AnsonNG thank you for transcribing my photo to mathjax